# Dynamic linq Binary and/or operator (Nhibernate linq)

Tags: nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I want to create an expression that as a result is a binary and or a binary or operation.
Something like

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = a & b; // d = 0
int e = a & c; // e = 1
```

I hav not found anything in dynamic linq! But in linq this is a normal expression!

```
public class Customer{
    [Flags]
    public enum Status{
        None = 0,
        Blocked = 1,
        Present = 2,
        Paid = 4
    }

// Holds the numeric status from database.
    public int CustomerStatusValue{get; set;}
}



var listOfCustomers = new List<Customer>(); // Would load from db...
// This works in linq
var result = listOfCustomers.Where(c => (c.CustomerStatusValue & 3) != 0); 

// This does not work!!!
var result = listOfCustomers.AsQueryable()..Where("(CustomerStatusValue & 3) != 0");
```

Comment: I think you should remove your edit and add it as your own answer, then accept it. Stack Overflow encourages this. You have elaborated your own answer, maybe with the help of mine but resulting in an answer more suitable to you, so adding your own answer should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) supports most common operators, but not all. There are a lot of things doable in Linq which are not doable with dynamic Linq.

I have just checked a [forked code](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs) from it, it does not support binary `&` and `|`. (The original code seems to be no more available on msdn: that was just a VS2008 sample, and those samples look retired now.)

Comment: Thank you for your interest! Is there a possibility to create a static class in a System.Linq.Dymic namespace to extend the functionality without forking the whole project? Maybe something like 'bool BinAnd(a, b)'?

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible. But this samples is originally only one source file to include in your project. Assemblies are non-official. Better take directly the source, and try if you can add binary operator support in it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Frédéric's suggestion, I downloaded the System.Dynamic.Linq file and changed it for '&' and '|' operatiors:

> ```
>   // +, -, &, | operators
>   Expression ParseAdditive()
>   {
>      Expression left = ParseMultiplicative();
>      while (token.id == TokenId.Plus || token.id == TokenId.Minus ||
>          token.id == TokenId.Amphersand || token.id == TokenId.Bar)
>      {
>         Token op = token;
>         NextToken();
>         Expression right = ParseMultiplicative();
>         switch (op.id)
>         {
>            case TokenId.Plus:
>               if (left.Type == typeof(string) || right.Type == typeof(string))
>                  goto case TokenId.Amphersand;
>               CheckAndPromoteOperands(typeof(IAddSignatures), op.text, ref left, ref right, op.pos);
>               left = GenerateAdd(left, right);
>               break;
>            case TokenId.Minus:
>               CheckAndPromoteOperands(typeof(ISubtractSignatures), op.text, ref left, ref right, op.pos);
>               left = GenerateSubtract(left, right);
>               break;
>            case TokenId.Amphersand:
>               if (IsNumericType(left.Type) && IsNumericType(right.Type))
>               {
>                  left = GenerateBinaryAnd(left, right);
>               }
>               else{
>                  left = GenerateStringConcat(left, right);
>               }
>               break;
>            case TokenId.Bar:
>               if (IsNumericType(left.Type) && IsNumericType(right.Type))
>               {
>                  left = GenerateBinaryOr(left, right);
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                  left = GenerateStringConcat(left, right);
>               }
>               break;
>         }
>      }
>      return left;
>   }
>
>
>   Expression GenerateBinaryAnd(Expression left, Expression right)
>   {
>      return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.And, left, right);
>   }
>
>   Expression GenerateBinaryOr(Expression left, Expression right)
>   {
>      return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Or, left, right);
>   }
> ```

I replaced the ParseAdditive function and created two new funtions that make a binary operation. So things like .Where("(a & B) > 0") now wioll work!!!!

It is not a final version because there are missing error checks and the name of the function 'ParseAdditive' maybe is not the right place or name, but it works.